# How to create a dataframe from a csv file , where the data is stored accumulated in a single column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let me assume I read a dataframe from a CSV file like ,

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").load(path)
```

And the df1 is like,

```
_c0 
________________
A B C D E
________________
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
_________________
A2 B2 C2 D2 e2
________________
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
```

And I want to convert it to.

```
A | B | C | D |
----------------
A1| B1|C1 | D1|

A2| B2|C2 | D2|

A3| B3|C3 | D3|

A4| B4|C4 | D4|
```

I can use **pyspark.sql.functions.substring** by finding the starting point and the length of eace field value. But is there any other method we can do?

```
outcs = (df1
   .withColumn("A",f.trim(f.substring("_c0",1,10).cast("string")))
   .withColumn("B",f.trim(f.substring("_c0",12, 36).cast("string")))
   .withColumn("C",f.trim(f.substring("_c0",49, 36).cast("string")))
   .withColumn("D",f.trim(f.substring("_c0",86, 36).cast("string"))))
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: A csv file is a **text** file. Read it with a text editor to know what separator is used.

Answer (score 2):

I might just be a matter specifying that you  have a header and giving the correct separator character. Try to play arround with these options:

```
spark.read.load(path,
                format="csv", sep="\t", header="true")
```

Here, `\t` is for tab separated values, but you can switch that to what ever value that is used as a separator. Another common separator values is `;`, so try setting `sep=";"` as well. The `header` option specify that the first line is used as a header.